# Redirect a page after download to update mysql table

Tags: php, mysql, href

I have a following code for download option:

```
<a href='http://xyz.net/video/<?php echo $row['video_name']?>' 
title='click to download this video'>
<img src="resources/images/icons/download.png"/>
```

Which works fine.

Now, I want to update my download table as

```
UPDATE video_uploaded SET downloaded = 1 WHERE video_id = '211' 
//here video_id is dynamic and it's not a problem
```

How is it possible to add redirect to another page option on this snippet:

```
<a href='http://xyz.net/video/<?php echo $row['video_name']?>'  
title='click to download this video'> 
<img src="resources/images/icons/download.png"/>
```

so that when user clicks on Download button first it downloads the file and then updates the table.

Comment: you want download to be finished and then DB entry ?

Comment: Only if you would use a proxy script to provide the file, or to add a trigger on the link that fires an AJAX call. The first will let it happen always, even when JS is disabled - the latter will only be triggered if javascript does it's work.

Comment: @CodingAnt Exactly and download works perfectly. But I am not getting how to redirect on other page to update table.

Comment: can you share download page code?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10480125/how-to-update-the-database-upon-successful-downloading see if this works for you

Answer (score 0):

I'd do something like this:

```
<a id='mylink' href='http://xyz.net/video/<?php echo $row['video_name']?>'  
title='click to download this video'> 
<img src="resources/images/icons/download.png"/>
```

And then using jQuery call the script to update the table:

```
$('#mylink').click(function(){
 $.post('script.php');
});
```

EDIT:

Due to the comments about checking successful download I'd try this:

```
$('#mylink').click(function(){
    $.post('downloadScript.php', function(data){
    if(data){
       $.post('updateScript.php');
     }
     else{
       // do whatever on failed download
     }
   };
});
```

Comment: how will you know from this that user has successfully downloaded the file or not ?

Comment: honest attempt , but @RakeshShetty is correct how will you ensure a successful download ?

Comment: to be that strict: I don't know of a solution to find out that the user downloaded the file, for example: user clicks download, confirms by pressing the save button and then cancels the download - how would you go about it? as far as I know you can only check the file was successfully sent to the browser

Comment: it is difficult to find wheater user has cancel the downloading or not. It is purely based on client side

Comment: using  ignore_user_abort(false)  and connection_aborted() ??