# A way to download a file and to verify if downoad i successful or it was canceled

Tags: php, html, download

Is there a way to download file and a way to 'track' that download progress and see if download is completed/successful or if it was canceled?

I'm in a position where I should update a state of the file in db upon successful download and I find it very hard to acquire the best way on how to accomplish that.

Over past few days I've been all over the stackoverflow and found very interesting answers, like:

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/8771378/1571756 where [Eugen Rieck](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1100552/eugen-rieck) fears that it's 'impossible' to determine if download is canceled.
- [how to update the database upon successful downloading?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10480125/1571756) where [Petah](https://stackoverflow.com/users/268074/petah) is pointing out that it cannot be done (or is extremely complicated) with the technology [Ahmad](https://stackoverflow.com/users/563466/ahmad) is using.

What is then the right approach/technology/... to detect successful download and update a db table?

Comment: Relevant: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1106377/detect-when-browser-receives-file-download

Comment: @ʰᵈˑ thanks. I think this will be of a great help!

Comment: The bigger question is: what would this tell you and isn't there a better way to handle that? Even if you can detect when the browser has technically successfully received all the data you sent it... there's still a million ways how that data did **not** end up saved as a file on the user's hard disk.

Comment: @deceze I agree! I'll have to come up with a way to handle that as well :-)

Comment: So you probably want an entirely different solution to begin with... what are you tracking that download for? How critical is it that this be 100% reliable? Why is it so critical, what purpose are you doing this for in the grant scheme of things?

Comment: Yes, I probably need to start from the scratch. The thing is that I track file statuses from upload to finalization, I list the files that are for download and after successful download the files should leave that list. I think that it's not that critical since I can come up with some way to handle 'broken downloads'.